# How can I use `Set-Disk` inside a PowerShell pipeline?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I am using the following PowerShell pipeline to reset a USB drive to my needs:

```
Clear-Disk -Number <NUMBER_OF_USB_DRIVE> -RemoveData -RemoveOEM -Confirm:$false -PassThru | New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter -IsActive | Format-Volume -FileSystem FAT32
```

After `Clear-Disk`, I'd like to insert `Set-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR`. The cmdlet accepts input objects from the pipeline, so I can use it and pipe objects *to* it. But it does not return any results and does not have a `-PassThru` parameter, so I can process objects *from* it further in my pipeline. It looks like `Set-Disk` can only be used at the end of a pipeline.

Are there other tricks available, so that I can use [`Set-Disk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/set-disk) *inside* a pipeline?

My current workaround looks like that:

```
Clear-Disk -Number <NUMBER_OF_USB_DRIVE> -RemoveData -RemoveOEM -Confirm:$false -PassThru | %{
    Set-Disk -InputObject $_ -PartitionStyle MBR
    New-Partition -InputObject $_ -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter -IsActive | Format-Volume -FileSystem FAT32
}
```

But I don't like it much, because technically a `Foreach-Object` should not really be necessary to process exactly one object.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `Set-Disk` at all? Isn't adding parameter `-MbrType FAT32` on `New-Partition` enough?

Comment: Why not use `Initialize-Disk` instead?

Comment: @Theo `-MbrType FAT32` does not change the partition type to MBR if it is already GPT.

Comment: @Seth `Initialize-Disk` does not work on already initialized disks. Removable media won't be un-initialized by `Clear-Disk`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Initialize-Disk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/initialize-disk?view=windowsserver2019-ps) would follow your requirements as it also supports `-PassThru`. As `Clear-Disk` is supposed to:

> Cleans a disk by removing all partition information and un-initializing it, erasing all data on the disk.

Using `Initialize-Disk` should be possible. Second example for it is:

> Example 2: Initialize a disk using the MBR partition style
>
> `Initialize-Disk -Number 1 -PartitionStyle MBR`

It doesn't look like you're currently doing more with `Set-Disk`.

Comment: I already had the same idea. Unfortunately, `Initialize-Disk` can only be called on RAW disks. It does not work on already initialized disks.

Comment: At least for me with a VHD (don't have a second drive available) `Get-Disk -Number 1  | Clear-Disk -RemoveData -PassThru | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter ` works without a problem even after the disk has been initalized (Windows 10 21H1). You're correct that you can use it to initalize a RAW disk but Clear-Disk turns that disk back into a RAW disk (as per the description of `Clear-Disk`).

Comment: I can confirm that `Clear-Disk` un-initializes virtual hard disks like you did. Unfortunately, `Clear-Disk` does not un-initialize a physical USB drive (tested with two different USB drives on two independent machines).